# WooCommerce - Sum of product_id values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the sum of specific product_id values in WooCommerce that are assigned to BACS payment gateway id. I have an array with the product id's and I am using array_sum to get the sum of the product values but this is not working correctly. If anyone could lead me in a better direction it would be much appreciated.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_total', 'invoice_price');

<?php
$available_gateways = $woocommerce->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
$invoiceItems = array(522, 550, 523);
$formatted_total = woocommerce_price( $this->order_total );

function invoice_price( $available_gateways ) {
  if ( $available_gateways == $gateways['bacs'] ) {
    foreach($product == in_array($values['product_id'])) {
         echo array_sum($invoiceItems);
    }
    $invoiceTotal = $formatted_total - $invoiceItems;
}
echo $invoiceTotal();
}
?>
```

Comment: Try `echo $invoiceTotal;` instead of `echo $invoiceTotal();` since `invoiceTotal` is not a function. (I was going to post it as an answer, but I didn't have the resources to fully test your code).

Comment: You can also try `$invoiceTotal = $formatted_total - array_sum($invoiceItems);` then do `echo $invoiceTotal;` --- this worked for me in testing to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

Having an array of 100, 200, and 300 would add up to 600.

`$formatted_total = 5000;`

I substract `$formatted_total` by the `$invoiceItems` array, 5000 minus 600 equals 4400.

```
<?php

$invoiceItems = array(100, 200, 300);

$formatted_total = 5000;

$invoiceTotal = $formatted_total - array_sum($invoiceItems);

echo $invoiceTotal; // will echo 4400

?>
```

`echo $invoiceTotal();` would render invalid because you are trying to echo an invalid function.

---

If I were to use the following:

```
$invoiceTotal = $formatted_total - $invoiceItems;
```

Will produce the following error:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types